# How to reconnect disconnected elbow in waste pipe?

Tags: plumbing, septic

I live in a mobile home community, the septic recently was overflown, it was pumped, however the main line connecting to the pipes in my house was "out of place" when the maintenance person "banged it back into place" with a 2x4, now the entire connection (elbow) and all came off, they're telling me that this is my issue and that I need to contact a plumber. 
Needless to say, a plumber is one hundred seventy five dollars per hour per person and this is a 2 man job. I am one woman but I am determined to fix it myself, I have done most of the home improvements already.

I can't find the correct connections needed, a diagram would be great but I am not sure where to find that either.

Comment: A photo of the broken or disconnected item would probably help people to work out what to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I second the comment that a photo would be helpful.  However, you might be able to use a flexible plumbing fitting such as those made by [Fernco.](http://www.fernco.ca/plumbing/flexible-couplings)